# UIWebView override swipe gesture

Tags: ios, gesture, swipe

I have a UIWebView that loads a page that captures left/right swipe gestures. So all swipe gestures are eaten up by the UIWebView, meaning that these gestures do not work within my app.

How do I:

1. Prevent the UIWebView from eating the left/right gestures, but still process all other events (such as swipe up/down to scroll)
2. Pass a two-finger swipe through to the UIWebView as a one-finger swipe.

Even if (1) is possible, that would be excellent!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
[self.view gestureRecognizers]
```

this will give you an array of the gesture recognisers from here you should be able to remove or change the action of the gesture recogniser.

Comment: The webview apparently does not use gesture recognizers in this way since the gestureRecognizers array is nil.